# How to make navigation look like this?

Tags: css, nav

I just really don't understand how I make the nav bar look like [image: example],

This is what I've got so far:

```
nav{
background-color: black;
padding: 20px;  
}
nav ul li {
display:inline;
margin: 10px;
```

Comment: This sort of seems like a homework question? Regardless, you could start by creating a jsfiddle for the project.

Comment: It is a homework question yeah, but this is the last part of it and I just  can't seem to recreate that nav bar

Comment: You want to use :hover commands with a list type in html <ul><li>home</li><li>about></li><ul>, I'll expand this later for you, just leaving work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully you take the time to understanding everything but I've made you a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/tXkw9/1/

That said, I would omit the navTop and use a border-top, I really just did this quick and dirty.

HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="navTop"></div>
     <div class="navBtm">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">About</a></li> 
         <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation{
    width:100%;
}

.navTop{
    height:5px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:red;
}

.navBtm{
    background:black;
    width:100%; 
    float:left;
}

.navBtm ul{
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.navBtm li{
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

.navBtm li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    font:Arial,sans-serif;
}


.navBtm li:hover{
    background-color:white;
}

.navBtm li:hover a{
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework so I won't be giving you the full answer, but this should give you everything you need.

- The li display should be inline-block OR block with float left http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp
- Then add a padding of about 20px to the li (instead of the nav)
- nav add border-top: 5px solid red;
- add  hover nav ul li:hover { background: white; color: black; }